How to convert this non-convex constraint into a convex bound using successive convex optimization?
The constraint is shown as follows,

$$\LARGE \|\mathbf{AA}^H\|_{F} \leq c$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix with dimension $K \times N$, $c$ is a given constant and the norm is $F$-norm. This constraint is obviously nonconvex, so how to find its convex transformation using successive convex approximation?
